# Excel to Text in a specific organized format

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string

I am trying to organize an elevation .xyz text file into a Visual Modflow 4.2 .VMG format for undergroundwater modeling. The specific format for the elevations goes like this:

(488 columns, 456 rows,3 layers)

(Layer 1, Column 1, from bottom to top rows)
 (7 spaces) Elevation1 (7 spaces) Elevation2....(7 spaces)Elevation10 (Next line) (7 spaces) Elevation 11....Elevation20 (next line)
...
Elevation 456
(Layer 1, Column 2, from bottom to top rows)

The .xyz file goes like this:

X coord (tab)   YCoord (tab)    Z Coord 
 I have it paste in the active excel sheet in the first 3 columns. It goes until around 300.000 rows.

So it goes from the first column through all of its rows from top to bottom.

The file I need to make does not specify the coordinates, they just assume the order from bottom to top and the coordinates are already set before in the desired order. So it is 10 elevations per line, separated by 7 spaces each.

```
`Private Sub Elevation_VMG()

Dim ElevacionesArray(1 To 488, 1 To 456) As Variant 'array with 3 layers, 
488 columns, 456 rows
Dim I As Integer 'counters
Dim J As Integer
Dim S As Integer
Dim C As Integer
Dim H As Integer
Dim MyFile As String


MyFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "C:\output.txt"
Close #1
Open "MyFile" For Output As #1

C = 2
For I = 1 To 488 '497 columnas
    For J = 1 To 456 '464 filas

       ElevacionesArray(I, J) = 
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(3, C).Value
        C = C + 1
    Next J
Next I


For I = 1 To 488
C = 1
    For J = 1 To 456
    If C >= 10 Then
    Write #1, vbNewLine
    C = 1

       'Array to textfile
        Write #1, "       " + ElevacionesArray(I, J)

        C = C + 1
    Next J
  Next I


 Close #1

End Sub`
```

I am still new at VBA for excel so i assume it is some formatting I am doing wrong, for now I get a 1004 error.

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: Your code is not compiling. Please fix this first, else I am afraid no one can help you.

Comment: You appear to have lost an `End If` - likely from just before `'Array to textfile` but we can't be certain.

Comment: You shouldn't put `Myfile` in quotes for the `Open` line. Not if you want to use the contents of your `MyFile` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up *obvious* errors in your code and commented where I've made a change to help you understand:

```
Private Sub Elevation_VMG()

Dim ElevacionesArray(1 To 488, 1 To 456) As Variant 'array with 3 layers,488 columns, 456 rows
Dim I As Integer 'counters
Dim J As Integer
Dim S As Integer
Dim C As Long ' 488*456 requires a Long to hold a number of that size
Dim H As Integer
Dim MyFile As String

MyFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\output.txt" ' Removed reference to C drive
Close #1
Open MyFile For Output As #1 ' Removed quotes

C = 2
For I = 1 To 488 '497 columnas
    For J = 1 To 456 '464 filas
       ElevacionesArray(I, J) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Hoja1").Cells(C, 3).Value ' swapped (3, C) row/columns here
        C = C + 1
    Next J
Next I

For I = 1 To 488
    C = 1
    For J = 1 To 456
        If C >= 10 Then
            Write #1, vbNewLine
            C = 1
        End If

        'Array to textfile
        Write #1, "       " + ElevacionesArray(I, J)
        C = C + 1
    Next J
Next I

Close #1

End Sub
```